# Error when controller route is referenced

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an ASP.NET core MVC app in which users can search for items to purchase. In this process, there is a search page which returns a list of results in a table where each item in the table is linked to a details page. Both the logic for the search page with the table and the logic for details page are contained in one controller. On the details page, I have an add to cart button which the user can click. This button is linked to a separate controller (for the shopping cart) than the one that is used for the actual details page.

For some reason, when I type in the url for the shopping cart controller action, there is the following error:

```
InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Models.ResortDataJoinObj' while attempting to activate 'Controllers.ShoppingCartController'.
```

The model in question here is being used to store data in the controller which is to be sent to the view. The model is working correctly when it's used in the other controller, so I'm not sure what the issue is here. For some reason though, when I click on the "Add to cart" button in the details view, the server can't find the page. **What could be causing these problems here?**

Below is the relevant code:

routes in starup.cs

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=resortDeals}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                routes.MapRoute(
                  name: "shoppingcart",
                  template: "{controller=ShoppingCart}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
```

relevant controller actions

```
    public class ShoppingCartController : Controller
    {
public ShoppingCartController(ResortDataJoinObj resortDataJoinObj, ShoppingCart shoppingCart)
            {
                _shoppingCart = shoppingCart;
                _resortDataJoinObj = resortDataJoinObj;

            }
     [Route("shoppingcart")]
    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        ...
    }
    [Route("ShoppingCart/AddToShopingCart/")]
    public RedirectToActionResult AddToShopingCart(int dealId)
    {
         var selectedDeal = (from rd in _db.ResortData
                                join ra in _db.ResortAvailability on rd.RecNo equals ra.RecNoDate
                                where Convert.ToInt32(rd.RecNo) == id
                                select new ResortDealResultsObject
                                {
                                    Name = rd.Name,
                                    ImageUrl = rd.ImageUrl,
                                    ResortDetails = rd.ResortDetails,
                                    RecNo = rd.RecNo,
                                    CheckIn = ra.CheckIn,
                                    Address = rd.Address,
                                    TotalPrice = ra.TotalPrice

                                }
                                );
            ResortDataJoinObj dealJoinObj = new ResortDataJoinObj();
            List<ResortDealResultsObject> selectedDealList = new List<ResortDealResultsObject>();
            foreach (var row in selectedDeal)
            {
                //An example of only selecting certain results
                // if (row.Name == "John" && row.TotalPrice > 15)
                // {
                var tempVm = new ResortDealResultsObject
                {
                    Name = row.Name,
                    ImageUrl = row.ImageUrl,
                    ResortDetails = row.ResortDetails,
                    RecNo = row.RecNo,
                    CheckIn = row.CheckIn,
                    Address = row.Address,
                    TotalPrice = row.TotalPrice
                };
                selectedDealList.Add(tempVm);
                //}
            }
            dealJoinObj.ResDealList = selectedDealList;
            if (selectedDeal != null)
            {
                _shoppingCart.AddToCart(dealJoinObj);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}

public class resortDealsController : Controller
    {

  public IActionResult Index()
        {
        }
 public async Task<IActionResult> Details(string id)
        {
        }
   }
```

details view:

```
@model Models.ResortDealDetailObject
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

<div>
    @Model.Name

    @Model.Address

    @Model.ResortDetails
</div>

@Html.Partial("AddToShoppingCart", @Model)
```

partial view:

```
 <div class="addToCart text-right">
        <p class="button ">
            @*<a class="btn btn-success" id="cartButton" asp-controller="ShoppingCart" asp-action="AddToShoppingCart" asp-route-id="@Model.RecNo">
                Add to cart
            </a>*@
            <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="search(@Model.RecNo)">
                Add to cart
            </button>
        </p>
    </div>
</form>

<script>
    function addToCart(recNo) {
        document.getElementById('cartForm').action = "/ShoppingCart/AddToShoppingCart/" + recNo;
        document.getElementById('cartForm').submit();
    }
</script>
```

Resort Data Join object:

```
public class ResortDataJoinObj
    {
        public ResortData ResData { get; set; }
        public ResortAvailability ResAvail { get; set; }
        public string priceLowEnd { get; set; }
        public string priceHighEnd { get; set; }
        public List<ResortDealResultsObject> ResDealList { get; set; }
        public ResortDealDetailObject detailObject { get; set; }
        public ResortDealResultsObject resortDeal { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Please show us the **constructor** for `ShoppingCartController`. Also, which IoC container are you using.

Comment: when you are loading the view from your controller i cannot see where you create the viewmodel object and pass it to the view. in the action that loads the view try creating the resortdatajoinobj and pass it to the view

Comment: @mjwills I just updated the post with the constructor. Also, what do you mean by IoC container? I'm still new at Asp .net

Comment: @JustLearning I first instantiate the viewmodel and then populate it with the query results. This object then gets stored in the shopping cart. This code is toward the bottom of the addToCart action.

Comment: your constructor is your problem

Comment: remove the two parameters from the constructor and your should be fine. Ioc is dependency injection container commonly used for service injection, which you need to first register.

Comment: @JustLearning If I remove the two parameters from the Shopping Cart constructor, how would the db context be initialized? I was doing it like that in the other class and it was working. Is this not standard practice?

Comment: You only need to remove the first parameter as its not required to be injected via the constructor... its just a model object nothing to do with initialized with the container.  As for your routes, you are using 2 very specific routes no honey pot routes, I would suggest having one below those 2 named default and then those rename the default to resortdeals, just my 2 cents.

Comment: Is ShoppingCart that is passed a DbContext of some sort?

Comment: @mvermef Lol, I guess I've been really tired lately. I didn't realize the first parameter was the viewmodel. I removed it and now if I enter the url https://localhost/ShoppingCart/AddToShoppingCart, the controller action is now being called. There is still the issue with the url not being found when trying to add a specific item to the cart as an id is being passed in the url. I'm tried using this as the route but it didn't work: `[Route("ShoppingCart/AddToShopingCart/{id}")]`

Comment: @mvermef  Also, what were you suggesting with the honey pot routes? I'm not familiar with those.

Comment: @mvermef Also, the ShoppingCart object being passed in was a view model. I was following [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UElG9AGKzpQ&t=7s). I'm not sure if what they are using best practices in the video though.

Comment: https://github.com/etrupja/DrinkAndGo/  now in there the Startup.CS you will see why he as the ability to use `IDrinkRespository` (this is called IOC, Inversion of Control, ie adding it to the container so it [the site] knows how to instantiate it from the Constructor).  I wouldn't normally pass ViewModels from 1 class to another like that, sorta breaks testability.  Another reason would be what if the ShoppingCart object is NULL?  You would really need to trap that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some answers inline

```
   // could be [Route("[controller]/[action]") or it could left off all together
   [Route("[controller]")]  
   public class ShoppingCartController : Controller
   {
      public ShoppingCartController(ShoppingCart shoppingCart)
      {
         _shoppingCart = shoppingCart;
      }

      // your default route...
      public IActionResult Index()
      {
        ...
       }
    [HttpGet("{id}")] //not entirely necessary either (more of a partially forced route)
     public RedirectToActionResult AddToShoppingCart(int id)
     {
        //since routes are exact missing something like {id} would cause
        //route generator to skip any calls to this without the {id} in place.
     }
  }
```

this should work... Since you had somethings that didn't include the {id} then the route doesn't match as you have written in the routing map, therefore you will experience what you are currently seeing.

Looking over the information you gleamed from the youtube video, I visited his repository to look at the example.  He actually has the ShoppingCart (ref. `startup.cs`) scoped so that its in what ever form (each individual cart, that is presently filled), via the IOC container.

Also keep in mind some of the configuration will vary now with that repository being about nearly 2 versions of .net core behind somethings with 2.1 are vastly different like not using `project.json` to reference assemblies for example.

Comment: So actually, the issue turned out to be that there was a typo in the name of the AddToShoppingCart method (check the code from the OP) so the view calling the method (which was using the correct spelling for the method) couldn't actually call it. Idk how no one caught that lol. I'll accept this answers since using explicit routes are also an option, but they actually didn't end up being needed here. I will have to add a service so that there can be DI in the class in order to get the code in the actual method to work as expected though.